# What are the pygame key names for number keys on an azerty keyboard?

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard, keyboard-layout, azerty-keyboard

What are the pygame key names for number keys on an azerty layout?
I need to know this to be able to properly detect key presses on an azerty layout which I don't have.

I have tried switching my mac keyboard layout to French - PC and the key namesshow up as:
`1234567890)=` when I would expect:
`&é”’(-è_çà)=`
In the pygame code base I do not see the french key codes.

Can someone with a France AZERY keyboard test this?
You can test it by running `python samples/pressed_keys_pygame.py azerty_laptop` from [this branch](https://github.com/spacether/keyboardlayout/tree/azerty_key_name_fixes) and pressing all the number keys in order and looking at the terminal input.

I get this info from pygame when using the `French - PC` layout:

```
{'unicode': '', 'key': 49, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 30, 'window': None} key_name = 1
{'key': 49, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 30, 'window': None} key_name = 1
{'unicode': '', 'key': 50, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 31, 'window': None} key_name = 2
{'key': 50, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 31, 'window': None} key_name = 2
{'unicode': '', 'key': 51, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 32, 'window': None} key_name = 3
{'key': 51, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 32, 'window': None} key_name = 3
{'unicode': '', 'key': 52, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 33, 'window': None} key_name = 4
{'key': 52, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 33, 'window': None} key_name = 4
{'unicode': '', 'key': 53, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 34, 'window': None} key_name = 5
{'key': 53, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 34, 'window': None} key_name = 5
{'unicode': '', 'key': 54, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 35, 'window': None} key_name = 6
{'key': 54, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 35, 'window': None} key_name = 6
{'unicode': '', 'key': 55, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 36, 'window': None} key_name = 7
{'key': 55, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 36, 'window': None} key_name = 7
{'unicode': '', 'key': 56, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 37, 'window': None} key_name = 8
{'key': 56, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 37, 'window': None} key_name = 8
{'unicode': '', 'key': 57, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 38, 'window': None} key_name = 9
{'key': 57, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 38, 'window': None} key_name = 9
{'unicode': '', 'key': 48, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 39, 'window': None} key_name = 0
{'key': 48, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 39, 'window': None} key_name = 0
{'unicode': '', 'key': 41, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 45, 'window': None} key_name = )
{'key': 41, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 45, 'window': None} key_name = )
{'unicode': '', 'key': 61, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 46, 'window': None} key_name = =
{'key': 61, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 46, 'window': None} key_name = =
```

Is pygame or my french keyboard layout not using the right scancodes? That's what it looks like because [these pc scancodes are different](http://kbdlayout.info/kbdfr/scancodes+scancodes). Do [key codes differ across platforms](http://web.archive.org/web/20100501161453/http://www.classicteck.com/rbarticles/mackeyboard.php)? My environment is MacOS 10.14.6 and when I type with the French - PC layout in other apps or in a tkinter terminal, the expected `&é”’(-è_çà)=` text is printed.

Per the above results it looks like pygame key values are the same as [keysym_num values for tkinter](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm). Also when using tkinter and logging key events; I am seeing different values for the pygame even.key/tkinter event.keysym_num values so it looks like pygame is handling these keys differently than I would expect. Tkinter looks like it is handling them correctly. These results are per my testing on a qwerty keyboard using a French - PC layout.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad English in advance. (i don't speak English natively)

Azerty layouts have it so that you have to have shift pressed to type the digits.

As seen here: [image: azerty layout]

While with qwerty layouts you don't need to press the schift key to type the digits. As seen here: [image: qwerty layout]

Hope you can solve the problem you are having.